# why feature hides in map after move it?

Tags: arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, feature-layer

I have a function that allows move a point by angle and distance
[image]

The problem is that after move the point, this doesn't show in map:
[image]

Sometimes the line also disappears

This is a summary of the code to update the coordinates of the point:

```
loFL = goMap.getLayer("points_layer");
//take the first graphic (The point) and update            
loFL.graphics[0].geometry.x = newX;
loFL.graphics[0].geometry.y = newY;                   
loFL.redraw();
```

**PD**: 'loFL' it's a FeatureLayer created with a FeatureCollection

Comment: Is `points_layer` a FeatureLayer or GraphicsLayer? If FeatureLayer are you creating it by sending a service URL?

Comment: it's a FeatureLayer, created with a FeatureCollection.

Comment: Which version of the JavaScript API are you using?

Comment: it's the version 3

Answer (score 2):

It looks like your code:

```
loFL = goMap.getLayer("points_layer");
//take the first graphic (The point) and update            
loFL.graphics[0].geometry.x = newX;
loFL.graphics[0].geometry.y = newY;                   
loFL.redraw();
```

Should indeed work fine for Feature Layers created with a [FeatureCollection](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/3/jsapi/featurelayer-amd.html#featurelayer2). [Code example here](https://jsfiddle.net/gavinr/21hqupd1/).

Comment: Yes, the layer was created with a FeatureCollection